# How to run typescript jest tests in eclipse 2020-12

Tags: typescript, eclipse, testing, jestjs

I have a typescript project with a test suite that can be run using `npm test` in the project directory from the console without a problem.

Is there a functionality in eclipse that would allow me to run the tests there, similar to how tests are run in Java?

The tests are run using jest, and I am using Eclipse version 2020-12.

Comment: Right-click `package.json`, choose _Run As > NPM..._ and enter as NPM command `test`.

Comment: That works, but it just runs the tests in the console. Isn't there an integrated way of running them, like with JUnit tests in Java that display the test results in a side panel and allow for jumping to wherever something failed?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet: https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues/578

Comment: @howlger: I took the liberty of converting your comment into an answer, hope that's ok :-).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Eclipse does not support running Jest tests, at least not in a fully integrated way (in a dedicated view, with clickable results etc.). As of October 2021, there is an open issue for this in the Wild Web Developer project:  [Add support for tests with Mocha #578](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues/578).

As a workaround, you can run the tests in the Eclipse console:

- right-click package.json
- choose Run As > NPM...
- enter as NPM command: `test`

*Thanks to howlger for explaining this in comments.*